# Extracting a two digit number from a string in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, numbers

I need to extract a two digit number from a string in python3.

** e.g. string is "1234" and I want the middle two numbers so I get 23.**

This isn't limited to just four letters, it could be hundreds.

Please could someone help?

Thank you as always!

Comment: Is the string always four characters?  If not, which digits would you use from, say, a five digit string `12345`?

Comment: Always drop the first and last characters? Or always skip the first, then use the next two only? Or use two before the last character?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it is not always four characters, it can be up to a few hundred. doctorlove, when it's a few hundred it, becomes complicated trying to drop the other numbers/skipping certain ones. Worst case scenario I can do that but I just wanted to see if there is a more efficient way. thanks

Comment: The simplest way is probably to make a list of the index you need and use a list comprehension on the string.

Comment: So what do you want as your result for `'1234567'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract two digits from the string "***1234"***

**str** function can be used.

**Code:**

```
 stringparse="1234"
 twodigit= stringparse[1]+stringparse[2]
 print(twodigit)
```

**Output**
Out[180]: '23'

Comment: Thank you very muc!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following line of code and it works for me.

```
value = '1234'

print(value[1:-1])
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:

With some more char in it.

```
value = '1234567'

m = len(value)//2

print(value[m:m+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick Google search ([this website](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python)), you should do:

`String = "1234"
ChoppedString = String[1:3] #Remember, the first letter is 0, the second is 1, etc.
print(ChoppedString)`

The [1:3] bit just means 'Start at the first letter, then get everything up to (but *excluding*) the second one.